Python: Trouble using the alt key with pydirectinput for task automation
As the title says, I'm working extensively with pydirectinput to manipulate some company software to automate a series of tasks.
The company software is heavily keyboard-driven but seems to be untouchable by pyautogui, so I decided that pydirectinput would be my next best bet. It has worked for everything in my automation script so far, but now I have run into a weird bug when I am using the alt key.
I ran into the issue after I had been testing my code and iterating to make minor tweaks. However, when I came the realization that I could use alt to activate the keyboard shortcut menu, I added some code in to do that. It would press alt twice to toggle the alt shortcuts and then press a couple other keyboard shortcuts, which opened a menu. I was then able to type an order number to search and continue pressing enter through the program without the alt shortcuts enabled anymore. Here is the current state of the methods that use the alt shortcuts:
def set_selection_mode(self):
        self.wmgr.find_window_wildcard(".*Order Entry.*")
        self.wmgr.set_foreground()
        self.wmgr.maximize_window()

        pydirectinput.press('alt')
        pydirectinput.press('alt')
        print("pressing m")
        pydirectinput.press('m', 1, 0.5)
        print("pressing s")
        pydirectinput.press('s', 1, 0.5)
        pydirectinput.press('shift')
        pydirectinput.press('shift')

        pydirectinput.press("enter", 3, 0.5)
        pyautogui.write("LB", interval=0.5)
        pydirectinput.press("enter", 2, 0.5)
def close_order(self):

        pydirectinput.press('alt')
        pydirectinput.press('c')
        pydirectinput.press('shift')

        time.sleep(0.25)

        pydirectinput.press('alt')
        pydirectinput.press('y')
        pydirectinput.press('shift')

        time.sleep(1)

It worked for the first few times, but then it started to do something weird. After trying to use alt in the close_order method, the alt shortcuts were somehow still enabled, and my code just started flailing randomly through the alt shortcuts and prevented it from writing text normally.
I'm a bit confused what's wrong with my code. I have tried adding a line to press alt again after entering the initial shortcuts, I have tried doing keyDown and keyUp instead of using press, and I have tried pressing an inconsequential key like shift to reset the alt shortcut mode, but none of these things worked. I ultimately had to reboot my computer to be able to use that program properly again.
Does anyone out there have any insight into this sort of use case for pydirectinput?
